# Can't create a view - BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Getting:

Table IDs may contain letters, numbers, and underscores.

Trying to save the view as:

`final-162619.final_project.GDELTblockchainVIEW`

Using standard SQL for my query and it outputs a simple joined table just fine. It looks to be an issue with the hyphen and periods, is there a way to escape those? Standard [] brackets didn't seem to work

Comment: In standard SQL you should use back ticks instead of brackets

Comment: I have the whole final-162619.final_project.GDELTblockchainVIEW in backticks and it's still giving me that error

Comment: can you confirm that your project name is `final-162619` and dataset name is `final_project` and, finally, actual expected view name is `GDELTblockchainVIEW`?! Also, if you can show piece of code you use - this will help us to help you :o)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe saving the view as `final-162619.final_project.GDELTblockchainVIEW` is possible in BigQuery because of the fact you've got periods and hyphens in it.

The [API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#resource) also clearly states this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can quote your project id, dataset name, and table name with backticks. You have to quote them individually. For example:

```
SELECT  `billing-address`
FROM    `my-project`.`shopify-import`.`the-orders`
```

(If you have underscores instead of hyphens they don't need quoting.)